# Reducing time-complexity of python (2.7) algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity, ironpython

I have in input a list consisting of three lists each representing the X, Y and Z coordinates respectively. For example:

```
coords = [[2, 1, 5, 2, 8, 6, 8, 6, 1, 2, 3 , 4], [1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 4, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8]]
```

where the list of coordinates X is: `X = [2, 1, 5, 2, 8, 6, 8, 6, 1, 2, 3 , 4]`

A point will be formed like this:`point = [2, 1, 2]`. A point XYZ represents a vertex of a cube. (In my program I have to analyze a set of stacked or side-by-side cubes).

As the output of the function, I would like a list of ID as large as the number of total points (= length of one of the coordinate lists). For different points the ID must be unique and incremented sequentially as the list of points is iterated. When a point had already been met (for example when a vertex of a cube coincides with the vertex of another cube), in the output list the point must have the ID that has the same point encountered first.

The result of the example should be `outp = [1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11]`

This is the code I wrote and it works perfectly:

```
def AssignIDtoNode(coords):

    outp = []
    n_points = len(coords[0])
    points = []

    memo_set = set()
    memo_lst = ["" for x in xrange(0, n_points)]

    for i in range(n_points):

        point = "(X = " + str(coords[0][i]) + ", Y = " + str(coords[1][i]) + ", Z = " + str(coords[2][i]) + ")"
        if punto not in memo_set:
            outp.append(i+1)
            memo_set.add(point)
            memo_lst[i] = point
        else:
            ind = memo_lst.index(point)
            outp.append(ind+1)
                
    return outp
```

The problem arises when in input to the function there is a very large list of points (millions of points) and the calculation time increases considerably. I have transformed each point into a string to facilitate searches and I used a set where possible to reduce the first search time.
In my opinion, the program takes a long time when it has to search for the index of a point through the .index () function.

Is there any way to further optimize this function?

Comment: Isn't this more of a code review question?

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: If possible, you really should switch to Python version 3.x .!

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate, zip and a dictionary to store the indices - `{(x,y,z):index,...}`

```
def f(coords):

    d = {}
    outp = []
    for i,punto in enumerate(zip(*coords),1):
        d[punto] = d.get(punto,i)    # if it doesn't exist add it with the current index
        outp.append(d[punto])
                
    return outp
```

---

Single pass through the points, no type conversions, constant time lookups.

```
>>> AssignIDtoNode(coords) == f(coords)
True
```

[zip and enumerate docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)

---

LBYL ...

```
def g(coords):
    outp = []
    d = {}
    for i,punto in enumerate(zip(*coords),1):
        if punto not in d:
            d[punto] = i
        outp.append(d[punto])        
    return outp
```

`g` is about 25% faster than `f` for 1 million and 3 million (x,y,z) points.

Comment: Using `OrderedDict` like that will only output the right result if there are no duplicates. And in any case, `OrderedDict` isn't implemented in C in Python2, so it will be much slower than the OPs original solution.

Comment: For a large list, using `get` is inefficient, because method calls are relatively expensive in Python. It would be more efficient to use a LBYL approach, which will also eliminate an extra lookup for missing keys.

Comment: Re your latest edits: as I said above, you cannot return the values from a mapping because it will remove all the duplicates and  thus give the wrong output...

Comment: @ekhumoro - yea I realized that while I was walking my dog.  Thmx.

Comment: Your LBYL example can save more lookups like this: `if punto not in d: d[punto] = i; else: i = d[punto]; outp.append(i)`. But I think an even faster solution is possible using `setdefault`, which almost reduces to a one-liner: `d = {}; outp = [d.setdefault(c, i) for i, c in enumerate(zip(*coords), 1)]`. This can also be improved a little more by caching the `setdefault` method: i.e. `d = {}; sd = setdefault; [sd(c, i) ... ]`.

Comment: ..@ekhumoro - in mS for 3e6 points: `g`-650; first setdefault comprehension - 510; second with the cache - 465.

Comment: May not be representative as there are **lots** of *duplicate* points.

Answer (score 0):

use dict that mapping from point to index

```
def AssignIDtoNode(coords):

outp = []
n_points = len(coords[0])
points = []

memo_dict = dict()

for i in range(n_points):

    point = tuple(coords[0][i],coords[1][i],coords[2][i])
    if point not in memo_dict:
        outp.append(i+1)
        memo_dict[point] = i+1
    else:
        ind = memo_dict[point]
        outp.append(ind+1)
            
return outp
```

Comment: Why do you need both `memo_dict` and `memo_set`?  You could just check `if point not in memo_dict`, which is just as efficient.  Also, you could have just used `point = (x, y, z)` rather than building a string.  Tuples make great dictionary keys.

Comment: you right, I took the original code and replace his list with dict, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it in linear time with a single pass using a list comprehension with an internal dictionary:

```
coords = [[2, 1, 5, 2, 8, 6, 8, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
          [1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
          [2, 4, 7, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 8]]

IDs = [d[c] for d in [dict()] for c in zip(*coords) if d.setdefault(c,len(d)+1)]

print(IDs)
# [1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```